# Why do Vi and Emacs have Stack Exchange sites but other tools don't?

Tags: discussion, network-sites

According to the **Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results**:

- these are the [most popular development environments and tools in 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#development-environments-and-tools).
- and these are [the most popular ones in 2017](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology-most-popular-developer-environments-by-occupation) by occupation.

Visual Studio ([Plain](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) & [Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)) get a top position.
Top for all development occupations and second for sysadmin/devops ones.
If both are added together they get about 69%.

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) get also a very good position.
Between 28% to 32% depending on occupations, but not as good as Visual Studio ones.

Traditional IDEs, like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) (sorry [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)...) also score well.

[Vim](https://www.vim.org/) gets a 25.8% for all respondents in 2018. [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) gets a small 4.1%.
Vim usage also boosts for sysadmin/devops occupations that gets about 40%.
There is [Vi/vim Stack Exchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).
There is also an [Emacs Stack Exchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

I have used all the ones I have mentioned, and some others.
Being currently an Emacs user, I wonder why Emacs got that small result.
Though I think somehow I know the answer and the reasons.

But what really amazes me is that ***Vim and Emacs both have Stack Exchange sites***.
And none of the rest have a site. Isn't that curious?

Why do you think is that?

- Is it because they have been around more time than the rest?
- Is it because their user community is dedicated and love its tool?
- Is it because they have their own language or scripting mechanism?
  (which allows the user to tweak and tinker them to the unlimited)
- Is it because they are open source?

Comment: Those sites went through Area51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/ and then launched. Maybe for the other tools/IDE's its userbase isn't that passionate.

Comment: They where both proposed on area 51 and got a large enough following to be moved into beta and it seems that emacs got far enough along to graduate while vi and vim is still in beta

Comment: vim is just the most intuitive editor ever. `:wq`

Comment: Who wants those icky kinds of questions here? Be off with them, the primitive ruffians.

Comment: Who are you talking to, @Will ?

Comment: Ok @Will, I went to http://idownvotedbecau.se, so why did you do it in this case?

Comment: Because an SE site for an good editor would not get any questions.

Comment: According to frequentation and upvote: every  1 Stackoverflow save 3 peoples from beeing trap in vim : ["How to exit the Vim editor?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor). Those Tools build their Community using the [Stockholm syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome)

Comment: @CrisLuengo What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, sorry! I may have been lost in translation from English to Spanish. Good day!

Comment: Because the other tools are good enough to not warrant a separate site.

Answer (score 24):

First and foremost, because they asked for them. They built a community that could support a separate site and [went through our process for getting such a site built](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Second, these tools are sufficiently complicated to require *highly* specialized knowledge. If you are at all used to standard desktop GUI tropes, then Visual Studio, VS Code, Notepad++, etc are things that you can do basic stuff in. You know where to find menu options, you have some idea how to do standard operations like copy and paste, etc.

Emacs and Vim aren't like that. Vim is *infamously* obtuse for the novice user. Emacs is practically a development *platform*. Both tools require a fairly high degree of knowledge before you can achieve minimal functionality. And both tools have an exceptional degree of depth.

Nobody makes a game that executes in Visual Studio. Well, I suppose a plugin *could*, but you don't see that happen with any regularity.

This is also why we have a website for TeX, but not for Microsoft Word or Libre Office Writer. Yeah, they "technically" do "the same thing" to a first order approximation, but you're really talking about the difference between shooting a bullet and *throwing* it.

Third, on a smaller note, there are a lot of emotions around Emacs and Vim that don't really exist for other tools. Questions regarding some complexity of one of them can occasionally attract comments from passionate users of the other tool. That's a lot less likely to happen if they live on their own site.

Comment: Good point regarding the human emotions that arise regarding Emacs & Vim... ;-)

Answer (score 11):

It's worth noting that Emacs isn't a text editor or IDE: it's a programming language platform for building a customized text editor or IDE.

Vim is not quite a platform in the same way that Emacs is, but it's still far *more* of a platform than traditional "out-of-the-box" IDEs like IntelliJ, Eclipse, or Visual Studio.

I have rarely seen a user of Eclipse or Visual Studio that has written code for extending it. However, nearly *every* serious user of Emacs or Vim ends up writing code to extend their editor eventually.

As a result, questions about these tools are very different. Questions about Eclipse or Visual Studio tend to be "which checkbox do I check in the configuration to get this behavior?" or "which plugin do I install to get this behavior?" Existing sites tend to handle those kinds of questions well.

Additionally, there is arguably less of a need for a Stack Exchange style Q&A platform for a tool that is easier to learn to use. Since Emacs and Vim are among the hardest tools to learn to use, it makes sense that they generate more Q&A activity.

Comment: Nice point... Strange you are not joined to `Emacs` Stack Exchange site...

Comment: I'm a vim guy, what can I say?

Comment: May be you can try `evil-mode`... he he

Comment: @nephewtom: For what it's worth, if you do a lot of sysadmin or devops work, you end up working on *lots* of different machines throughout the day. Some flavor of vi or vim is installed practically *everywhere*, but emacs is rarely installed out of the box. So in that kind of workflow you find a lot of people who prefer vim.

Comment: Yep, I know that. I am kind of kidding here. You could just play with Emacs in your spare time. Even though I started to use Emacs for work back in 1997, I have learnt much about it because I **play** with it and I enjoy it as a toy.

Comment: *"I have rarely seen a user of Eclipse or Visual Studio that has written code for extending it"* There sure are a lot of plug-ins available for download. *Someone* has to be writing them.

Comment: @CodyGray maybe they just haven't met any of those people.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the SE doesn't see technologies, they see communities. The Area51 is before you. You can initiate a community about any technologies you like. The question is, if they would get the required support.

Btw, vi/vim is much more than an ncurses-based text editor. It is such a complex IDE like eclipse or the others.

P.s. what counts as "traditional", depends on the first softwares you've faced. For me, "vi" is "traditional".

Comment: I would not call vi/vim an IDE. Not in the common sense. vi is... well... hum... fizz...tick... tick... tick... buzz... ahh... ding dong... splash... beep beep... well... vi is vi.

Comment: @Nephewtom You're right, it's far better than any IDE.

Comment: @DavyM IDE = "integrated development environment". My most loved softwares are: screen + ssh + vim + make + bash + gcc. They integrate very well. :-)